# New to automation outside of Selenium - Is Ranorex suitable for a larger web-app?

Tags: automation, ranorex

I've been experimenting with Selenium to some success, however it's slow going.

Ranorex, as I've used briefly in the past can put a simple suite of tests together rather quickly. However, I'm concerned about scale-ability. The website I'm interested in automating testing for is fairly large in terms of how much test coverage it requires.

Watching video tutorials on modulating test steps gives me the impression that Ranorex isn't designed to really support a larger size web-app with detailed testing parameters.

How big are the projects you use Ranorex for and how do you manage your tests and suites? How do you keep it organized?

Answer (score 0):

Ranorex provide Suite and Group module where you can add multiple test casew grouped them. Also it provide  configuration at suite level where you can grouped set of test cases from suite. So when you run that particular configuration from suite then selected test cases will execute.

I have used Ranorex where we have approximate 1000+ test cases( scenario based ).

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks
Sadik